# order of element out of index 2 subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to prove an assertion a friend told me.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup of index $2$. Then every element of $G$ not in $H$ has even order.

What I did: Since $H$ is a index $2$ subgroup it is normal, so considering the quotient group $G/H$ which is a group of order $2$, by Lagrange we get $g^2 \in H$ $  \forall g \in G$ . Any further help? (Forgot to mention: I'm not saying this is the right way to prove the assertion, i just said what I tried in order to prove the assertion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $2k + 1$ is the order of $x$, then $x^{-1} = x^{2k} \in H$, by considering the quotient. Since $x^{-1} \in H$, we must have $x \in H$, since $H$ is a subgroup. Thus, if $x$ has odd order, $x \in H$, so by the contrapositive, if $x \in G - H$, $x$ has even order.